# i get error 'FileProvider' of undefined using record function with nativescript-videorecorder

Tags: nativescript

i need help.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'FileProvider' of undefined`

I get that error when i try to record.

- Code:

```
const options: VideoRecorderOptions = {
            hd: true,
            saveToGallery: true
        }
        const videorecorder = new VideoRecorder(options)
        videorecorder.record().then((data) => {
            console.log(data.file)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

Comment: Where do you access "FileProvider" in your code?

Comment: The documentation dont specific how do that. I dont find how set fileprovider property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Android X compatibility issue, the plugin author will have to update the plugin to support {N} 6.x and later.

[android.support.v4.content.FileProvider](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-videorecorder/blob/master/src/videorecorder.android.ts#L94-L95) is now [androidx.core.content.FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider). You may update the code and compile it locally as a workaround.